# Exclude all pages that begin with "/screens" EXCEPT "/screens/company-setup-details" in Google Analytics Segment filtering

Tags: regex, google-analytics, analytics

I've been traversing several questions that parallel mine, but can't seem to figure this out one. As the title implies, I need to solve for the following:

**Exclude all pages that starts with "/screens" EXCEPT "/screens/company-setup-details".**

I've tried to build this on http://regexr.com with no luck so far. I feel it's an easy solve, but I'm having a difficult time figuring out the broad exclusion, and minor inclusion.

I wanted to add, that some examples in this would be: "/screens/home", "/screens/login", and "/screens/embed-setup".

Comment: GA does not support negative lookahead, so I do not think this will work. What you can try (untested) is to use a replace filter on the request url to rename /screens/company-setup-details to something else, then do an exclude filter and "screens", then rename the page to the original name. Since filters are applied in the order that they are set in the admin interface this might just work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^/(?!screens(?!/company-setup-details))
```

Excludes all paths that begin with `/screens`, except if it is followed by `/company-setup-details`.

**Explanation:** it is double negation logic. For the first negative lookahead to "pass" (i.e. not match), then the negative lookahead inside of it must also pass (not match).

Note that the expression above will match:

- All paths besides those that begin with `/screens`
- All paths that begin with `/screens/company-setup-details`

If, instead, you would like to match only the ignored paths, then use:

```
^/(screens(?!/company-setup-details))
```

---

**Update:** GA regexps no longer support negative lookahead since 2009, hence my expressions above will not work. Here's an ugly hack that should do the job though:

```
^/(?:(?:[^s]|$)|s(?:[^c]|$)|sc(?:[^r]|$)|scr(?:[^e]|$)|scre(?:[^e]|$)|scree(?:[^n]|$)|screen(?:[^s]|$)|screens/company-setup-details)
```

[Regexr](http://regexr.com/3agm4).

If you don't mind excluding paths which are leading substrings of `screens` (e.g. if the whole path is `/scr` or `/scree`), then you can simplify the regexp a bit:

```
^/(?:[^s]|s[^c]|sc[^r]|scr[^e]|scre[^e]|scree[^n]|screen[^s]|screens/company-setup-details)
```

[Regexr](http://regexr.com/3agm7).

FWIW I generated the negation part using this JavaScript code:

```
var str = '';
var ret = '';
'screens'.split('').forEach(function(c) {
    ret += (ret ? '|' : '') + str + '(?:[^' + c + ']|$)';
    str += c;
});
'(?:' + ret + ')';
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I set up an example here: http://regexr.com/3aghk using your above exp, and loaded up some sample data. I tweaked a few things, but couldn't get it working properly, though that could be specific to the regexr tool?

Comment: I may have found a solution here combining a few things from your answer, and another that I finally came across on the site.

^(?=.*?\bscreens\b)((?!company-setup-details).)*$

I'm still playing with it to see, but the combination could work, though I wasn't able to get your original example working properly

Comment: Well, I'm able to get it working in my example, but not in Google Analytics. Still have to dig deeper and see why it's not working properly.

Comment: I don't think GA regexp supports negative lookahead, that's why this does not work.

Comment: Eike is right, this [Google Analytics Regular Expressions Cheat Sheet](http://www.cheatography.com/jay-taylor/cheat-sheets/google-analytics-regular-expressions/) does not list negative lookahead -- in fact, it doesn't list any lookaround, so it will be hard (impossible?) to achieve what you're looking for, @stebesplace.

Comment: Well that explains why for hours, I couldn't get it to work in GA! @FabrícioMatté let me plug in your answer to give it a go, and curious about the JS code to generate - this may be something I do more of, so good to see there's options for generating.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Okay, looks like the regex works, but it's only selecting the /screens/company-setup-details (should be like how your first example was outlined). I'm trying to reverse it.